# How can I create a model which is starts with a single convolution layer and then its output given to two different convolution layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

Can I generate a Model in keras which is not sequencial, i.e can I design a model with two train of cascaded convolution layer but the starting input is a common convolution output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You just need to use the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models).

e.g.

```
main_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

conv_1 = Conv1D(32, 3)(main_input)

conv_2 = Conv1D(64, 3)(conv_1)

conv_3 = Conv1d(64, 3)(conv_1)
```